# Laravel Pusher http://localhost:8000/broadcasting/auth 404 (Not Found) and http://localhost:8000/messages

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, pusher

I am Following the Pusher-Laravel Chat documentation, and i did everything that they said. when i tested it the message are not being recieved in the other user. I already Uncommented the BroadCastServiceProvider and im running queue:listen.
when i inspect the Console gave me this.

```
You are running Vue in development mode.
Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html
app.js:33178 POST http://localhost:8000/broadcasting/auth 404 (Not Found)
ajax @ app.js:33178
PusherAuthorizer.authorize @ app.js:35577
PrivateChannel.authorize @ app.js:35700
Channel.subscribe @ app.js:35769
Pusher.subscribe @ app.js:32811
Pusher.subscribeAll @ app.js:32801
(anonymous) @ app.js:32706
Dispatcher.emit @ app.js:34132
ConnectionManager.updateState @ app.js:36146
connected @ app.js:36082
callback @ app.js:35959
cb @ app.js:36527
tryNextStrategy @ app.js:36342
(anonymous) @ app.js:36392
(anonymous) @ app.js:36248
Handshake.finish @ app.js:35333
onMessage @ app.js:35309
Dispatcher.emit @ app.js:34132
TransportConnection.onMessage @ app.js:34035
socket.onmessage @ app.js:34052
app.js:33211 Pusher : Couldn't get auth info from your webapp : 404
warn @ app.js:33211
xhr.onreadystatechange @ app.js:33173
app.js:712 POST http://localhost:8000/messages 500 (Internal Server Error)
dispatchXhrRequest @ app.js:712
xhrAdapter @ app.js:549
dispatchRequest @ app.js:1230
app.js:774 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
at createError (app.js:774)
at settle (app.js:1308)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:614)
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you remember to uncomment `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider` in `config/app.php`?

Comment: yeah i uncommented it but it still produced the same error :(